# Where to put comma or how to rephrase? I need a plum, and an apple or a pear

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation, commas

How to write the sentence, where to put a comma or how to rephrase:
**"I need a plum, and an apple or a pear".**

Meaning: I will be satisfied if I have a plum and an apple OR a plum and a pear.

Comment: If you put the comma (pause, in speech) after "apple", that means you'll be satisfied if you have a plum and an apple OR if you just have a pear. It's agnostic as to how you'd feel about getting just a plum, OR getting a plum and a pear. If you don't have *any* comma, the text is inherently ambiguous, and *nobody* could be 100% certain about what to give you in order for you to be satisfied (you might not be at all happy about getting all three fruits, if that would be awkward to carry, too expensive, or whatever).

Comment: That comma is incorrect. You can place a comma before the final element in a series of 3+ noun phrases, but not before the second element in a pair. The fact that the pair is followed by a third element does not change that. You cannot solve this puzzle with punctuation.

Comment: This is a classic "Apple" question.  Do you really want to talk about fruit?  Is there a real situation that occurred in which this was a problem.  It would be good if you told us the real situation too!  The Apple question might help by making it simpler, but the answer might be wrong for your real situation.

Comment: As it stands, this question is a request for proof-reading, which is off-topic on this site, so I'm closing it to new answers. Please edit it (using the small "Edit" button under the question) so it's clearly about a grammar topic, rather than about the correctness of your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is correct as given. Placing a comma after "plum" helps to separate "plum" from "apple" and "pear", so I think that is helpful and correct.

Nevertheless, the sentence is likely to be misunderstood by some. Many listeners would wonder whether you mean "(a plum) and (an apple or a pear)" or "(a plum and an apple) or (a pear)", or would guess wrong. And some would think you mean a plum or an apple or a pear, one of the three.

I think computer programmers and mathematicians would think "okay, we need to see how to group this correctly, and would take the comma after "plum" as an indication. But I suspect most people not in these professions wouldn't think it out that carefully.

If I was trying to clearly communicate this idea, I think I'd use more words. Like, "I need two pieces of fruit, either a plum and an apple or else a plum and a pear". Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have placed your comma correctly but why not something clearer such as:

*I need a plum and either an apple or a pear.*